# Why is my DOS program crashing after I memset an array of 64 thousand `int`s?

Tags: c, x86-16, dos, turbo-c

I have a problem with  `memset` and a big for loop in Turbo C.

I was programming a small Graphics library based on Mode 13h with Turbo C++ 3.00 on MS-DOS 6.22 on Virtual Box, when the code started crashing.

I know that Turbo C is really outdated, but I wanted to try the old-style coding on DOS like systems.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>

int main(void) {
  int *buf;
  unsigned int i;

  _AH = 0x0;
  _AL = 0x13;
  geninterrupt(0x10);

  buf = malloc(sizeof(int)*64000);
  memset(buf,15,64000); //can't figure out why memset does not work properly...

  for (i=0;i< (unsigned int)64000;i++){
    buf[i] = 15; //trying to forcely set each byte to 0xf...
    pokeb(0xA000,i,buf[i]); //outputting to VGA
  }

  getch();
  free(buf);
  return(0);
}
```

What I was trying to do was basically filling the screen with the white color.

Once I started coding I noticed that `memset` was not setting ALL of the bytes of my heap array to 0xf.

So I decided to set them manually by coding the for loop.

I ran it and it worked like butter. As soon as I poked the byte to the screen, the program crashed, and I couldn't figure out why...

Any help?

PS: I'm pretty new to C.

Comment: That `memset` should be `memset(buf,15,sizeof(int)*64000)` like the `malloc` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MS-DOS memory is organised in segments of no more than 64K.

Your buffer of 64,000 integers is larger than that.

If you used `unsigned char` (single bytes) instead of `int` or `unsigned int` (which I seem to remember are 16 bits in DOS/Turbo C++) then it would fit into a single segment and should work fine.

... And as you're storing bytes to be poked into video memory, you don't need the extra bit-width that integers give you.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dos.h>

int main() {
  unsigned char *buf;
  unsigned int i;

  _AH = 0x0;
  _AL = 0x13;
  geninterrupt(0x10);

  buf = malloc(64000);
  memset(buf, 15, 64000);

  for (i=0; i < (unsigned int)64000; i++) {
    pokeb(0xA000, i, buf[i]); //outputting to VGA
  }
  getch();
  free(buf);
  return(0);
}
```

As @Jabberwocky has mentioned, if you don't plan to do anything else but poke these values directly to video RAM, you can even ignore the buffer entirely:

```
int main() {
  unsigned int i;

  _AH = 0x0;
  _AL = 0x13;
  geninterrupt(0x10);

  for (i=0; i < (unsigned int)64000; i++) {
    pokeb(0xA000, i, 15); //outputting to VGA
  }
  getch();
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Actually replacing `buf[i]` with `0xf`and removing all malloc/memset/free should do the same thing.

Comment: you can change to big model where all data accesses are done via far pointers and it'll overcome the 64K issue

Comment: `int` and `unsigned` are definitely 16 bit on the Turbo C environment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky (re: don't use malloc at all) I was assuming that OP was going to do something else with his buffer once this issue is resolved... but, otherwise - yes, you're quite right.

Comment: @phuclv - oh yeah "far pointers" - now that takes me back to my youth - I'd forgotten they even exist... But do'nt you need to compile 16-bit specific code or something like that to use them?

Comment: My goal was to make a frame buffer array to store the entire frame in it, making the actual render faster, hopefully...

Comment: @SlickSpore: If you want to render into a (write-back cacheable) buffer and then copy to video RAM, you're going to want to copy efficiently with something like `memcpy`, not one byte at a time with potential function-call overhead!!  Unless `pokeb` inlines and can hoist the setup of a segment register (like ES) out of the loop.  If not, calling it 64k times is going to be way slower than only updating the changed pixels in video RAM.  Especially if video ram is uncacheable (without write-combining) so your 1-byte transfers all go separately, not even a 32-bit dword at a time, let along 64B.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If you include `dos.h` which the OP does, and if you don't undef the macro `pokeb` (which they don't) then it resolves down to an inline statement that makes use of MK_FP macro to create a far pointer and sets the value through that. The macro looks something like `void inline _Cdecl pokeb(unsigned __segment, unsigned __offset, char __value ) {( *( (char far* )MK_FP( __segment, __offset )) = __value ); }`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ok, so at least there won't be a function call.  Any idea if Turbo C++ would actually manage to hoist the setup of a segment register out of the loop for all those  `char far*` derefs with the same `__segment__`?  And/or optimize those char loads / stores into word or dword accesses to both `buf` and video RAM, or a `rep movsd`?  The fact that `pokeb` doesn't use `volatile` is surprising.  It's more likely to allow optimizations like write coalescing.  But if it actually works reliably without `volatile` for uses like MMIO, that probably meansthe compiler can't optimize much!

Comment: @AndyPreston you don't need to do anything, Turbo C already has built-in support for multiple memory models depending on how much data and code you need: [Memory models for assembly libraries for Turbo C](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12838/1981)